# Not understanding what's wrong with my Filter function and state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, onchange, setstate

I have the following code:

Parent component:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    colors: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const fetched = await fetch("./response.json");
    const fetchedJson = await fetched.json();
    const res = fetchedJson.colors;

    this.setState({
      colors: res
    });
  }

 
  filterItems = (name) => {
    const lowerCaseName = name.toLowerCase();
    const newColors = [...this.state.colors];
    const res = newColors.filter((color) => {
      const lowerCaseColorName = color.name.toLowerCase();
      return lowerCaseColorName.includes(lowerCaseName);
    });

    this.setState({
      colors: res
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { colors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <InputText filterItems={this.filterItems} />
        <AllData colors={colors} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my Child component:

```
class Filter extends Component {
  state = {
    inputVal: ""
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      inputVal: e.target.value
    });
    this.props.filterItems(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.inputVal}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Filter;
```

There's also another child component called `AllData` but its job is just displaying out data and put styling on it, so I'm not including it here.

Currently the data displayed are just:

```
Fire Dragon
Water Horse
Earth Bird
Wood Dog
Wind Cat
```

Here are my questions:

1. The `filter` function works fine when I type in a word into the search box in filter. However, when I backtrack and remove a previous character down to the whole input string, the `res` array doesn't return its whole original arrays but instead retains the result of the filter only when I type more.

Ex:
When I type in the string "cat", `res` becomes: `[{name: "Wind Cat", id: 5}`
However I remove that string by backtracking on the keyboard, `res` is still at `[{name: "Wind Cat", id: 5}`. **Why is it not going back to returning all of the items, and how do I fix this?**

2. I currently have this code:

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      inputVal: e.target.value
    });
    this.props.filterItems(e.target.value);
  };
```

However, if I change it to:

```
this.props.filterItems(this.state.inputVal);
```

and `console.log(name)` out in the parent component at `filterItems`, every time I type in a string, it seems like the console.logged `name` only display the character before.

Ex:
If I type in the string `c` -> `name` would be "" (empty)
If I type in the string `ca` -> `name` would be `c`
**Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      colors: [],
      filtered: [],
    };
  
    async componentDidMount() {
      const fetched = await fetch("./response.json");
      const fetchedJson = await fetched.json();
      const res = fetchedJson.colors;
  
      this.setState({
        colors: res
      });
    }
  
   
    filterItems = (name) => {
      const lowerCaseName = name.toLowerCase();
      const newColors = [...this.state.colors];

      const filtered = newColors.filter(color => {
        const parts = color.split(' ').map(part => part.toLowerCase());
        return parts.reduce((carry, part) => {
          return carry ? carry : part.startsWith(lowerCaseName);
        }, false);
      });

      this.setState({
        filtered,
      });
    };
  
    render() {
      const { colors, filtered } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>
          <InputText filterItems={this.filterItems} />
          <AllData colors={filtered ? filtered : colors} />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! Now here I'm wondering, if I have several objects like `Wind Cat`, `Fire Ca`, `Water C`, does this still work? It seems like the code would work if we enter a complete string in or if the search box is empty, but it wouldn't work when we backtrack by character one by one?

Comment: nope, your code will only work with a full string. you will have to come up with other methods of finding parts of strings. e.g. `startsWith` but this is the answer to why your array was disappearing. its because you were overwriting it when someone typed into the input.

Comment: @lolcatapril24 ive updated my answer with a better filter option for you.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you filter the array and thus lose the objects. what you can do is have 2 arrays, one with all the data and one with the filtered data. apply the filter to the array with all the data and set the filtered array to the result

Comment: Thanks! Why do I lose the objects when I filter the array, and could you give some example code, because I'm still pretty vague on it

Comment: @lolcatapril24 you lose the objects because the method filter returns a new array that only contains the objects that satisfy the condition, then you set your colors array in the state to that array.

Comment: check out the answer by Michael Mano, it contains the code you need